# How can I send POST data from android to php without using INTERNET permission?

Tags: php, android, post

I found many examples using INTERNET permission, is there any approach to send data to php without using  the permission?

Comment: If your application connects to the internet why would you not want to use the INTERNET permission?

Comment: exactly how do you propose to do an HTTP request (which uses TCP) **WITHOUT** using "internet"?

Comment: The only way i can think about is to send a text message with a stringified json to a receiver with an internet connection that can then post it to the server.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it is correct please. (or there is no better answer, meaning it is likely correct, especially with upvotes.)

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it is correct please. (or there is no better answer, meaning it is likely correct, especially with upvotes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no approach to do this, you need the internet permission as this allows android to use internet protocols (like TCP, Transmission Control Protocol which is one of the core protocols and is needed to send POST data -via a HTTP request-) So without the INTERNET permission there can be no data transference using internet protocols between android and the server (I'm assuming your are talking about the php being on a server).